# how can I remove the parenthesis from a string in JAVASCRIPT?

Tags: javascript

How can I remove the parenthesis from this string in Javascript "(23,45)" ? I want it to be like this => "23,45" please!

Comment: Let Google be your friend - I couldn't type fast enough to get an answer after searching "javascript string replace"

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Simply use [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) :

```
str = str.replace(/[()]/g,'')
```

If you just wanted to remove the first and last characters, you could also have done

```
str = str.slice(1,-1);
```

Comment: Dude thanks! It worked perfectly with not even the slightest problem.

Comment: I was confused about the "-1" for a second. Looked it up - apparently if you use negative numbers with string.slice, the number will count from the end of the string instead of the start.

Answer (score 2):

```
str = str.split("(").split(")").join();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) function

```
var a = "(23,45)";
a = a.replace("(","").replace(")","")
```

Answer (score 1):

If they're always the first and last characters:

```
str = str.substr(1, str.length-2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
"(23,45)".replace("(","").replace(")","")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this regex

```
var s = "(23,45)";
alert(s.replace(/[^0-9,]+/g,''))
```